# How can I make my backgroundColor in Chart.js match up with a reversed order y axis?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to get my background color working properly in Chart.js.  I've reversed the order of my y-axis ticks.  Now my background color has been flipped as well.  It fills from the border line to the top of the graph, not from the border line towards the x-axis like I'd like it to.

Here [is my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ed6t407e/).  My code is:

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Rank',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#8FBC8F"
        }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

I've read through the Chart.js documentation with no luck, which makes me think it might not be possible.  I wanted to see if anyone else has run into this problem and if they found a solution.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to add fill: 'start'.

Check

```
    var options = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
      labels: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
      datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Rank',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              borderWidth: 1,
              backgroundColor: "#8FBC8F",
              fill: 'start'
            }
            ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                        reverse: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, options);
```